# How do I use Accelerate BLAS to solve sparse matrix linear equation?

Tags: ios, swift, matrix, linear-algebra

In an iOS app, I need to solve a linear equation Ax = B, where A is a sparse matrix with 40K rows and 10K columns.

Accelerate has a Sparse Solver package, but it is still in beta:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/sparse_solvers

I wonder if I can use [BLAS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/blas) to solve the linear equation? BLAS contains functions to define a sparse matrix, but I don't see any solver functions.

Comment: Come to think about it, this is a linear regression problem. Is there any efficient way to do a linear regression? Using Metal or Accelerate?